# add or no margin left in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi everyone I am using bootstrap for my projects very recently and sasss, and I have a question?

what is the different between

```
.row-fluid.span12
```

and

```
.row-fluid
  .span12
```

In both case I create a row (responsive) and 1 column to occupy all width, why in the fist case they put a left margin, and the second one no?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are selecting all the`span12`'s that are the descendent of `row-fluid` using the following: (assuming that your syntax is correct)

```
.row-fluid
  .spand12
```

for a possible scenario like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="span12">
            ...
        </div>

        <div class="span12">
            ...
        </div>
</div>
```

The other selector corresponds to a possible scenario like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid span12">
```

I am assuming that you probably know all this, but I thought it might help.